# UNPIVOT SQL Server vs TERADATA

Tags: sql-server, teradata, unpivot

I am trying to translate the following query from SQL Server to Teradata:

```
SELECT 
    pfl_id, Monthno, objRecd
FROM
    (SELECT 
         pfl_id, 
         ObjOctobre, ObjNovembre, ObjDecembre,
         ObjJanvier, ObjFevrier, ObjMars,
         ObjAvril, ObjMai, ObjJuin,
         ObjJuillet, ObjAout, ObjSeptembre
     FROM 
         fraccp_fls.sf_target_portfolio_load) stu
 UNPIVOT
 (objRecd FOR Monthno IN (ObjOctobre
  ,ObjNovembre
  ,ObjDecembre
  ,ObjJanvier
  ,ObjFevrier
  ,ObjMars
  ,ObjAvril
  ,ObjMai
  ,ObjJuin
  ,ObjJuillet
  ,ObjAout
  ,ObjSeptembre)
  ) AS mrks) as req
```

Is there an equivalent for `Unpivot` in Teradata 15.10 ? If not - how would I do it?

Thank you

Comment: You might try the documentation. http://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/General_Reference/B035-1098-160K/rnz1472240714147.html A quick google search reveals that UNPIVOT is a new feature in version 16.

Comment: Yes I found that but is there any way to have the same result with other functions ?

Comment: I suspect you will have to use UNION like we used to have to do in sql 2000 and earlier.

Comment: `PIVOT/UNPIVOT` syntax was introduced in TD16: http://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/vpq1472240905673.html#, but it's using `TD_UNPIVOT` in the background which exists since TD14.10 (?): http://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/SQL_Reference/B035-1145-160K/pmj1472240925470.html#wwID0EJRAM